# Как изменить функцию класса для каждого его объекта?

Tags: c++

Можно ли изменить функцию, объявленную в классе, для каждого его объекта по своему, и если можно то как это сделать?

Comment: Может вам нужны указатели на функции?

Comment: Уточните, *как* и *зачем* вы хотите её изменить?

Answer (score 3):

Функцию класса для каждого объекта не изменить - адрес такой функции прописывается либо при компиляции, либо в таблице виртуальных функций, и для всех объектов одинаков.

Другое дело, что можно хранить указатели на функции (или, скажем, объекты `function<>`) в объектах класса и вызывать их. Что-то вроде

```
class Horror
{
public:
    Horror(function<void(void)> f):f(f){}

    void operator()() { f(); }

private:
    function<void(void)> f;
};


void out() { cout << "Out\n"; }

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Horror h1(out), h2([](){ cout << "Lambda\n"; });

    h1();
    h2();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к посту Harry, работающий вариант с указателями на функции.

```
#include <iostream>

typedef void (*func_ptr)(int);

class TestClass {
public:
    func_ptr  method;
};

void method_plus(int _arg) {
    std::cout << _arg + 1 << std::endl;
}

void method_minus(int _arg) {
    std::cout << _arg - 1 << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    TestClass tc1, tc2;

    tc1.method = method_plus;
    tc2.method = method_minus;

    tc1.method(42);
    tc2.method(42);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Правда, насколько я понимаю, в обоих вариантах будут проблемы с обращением к переменным-членам класса изнутри этих функций.

Не очень понятна задача, зачем это нужно; с конкретным примером было бы понятнее.

UPD: Этот же вариант, но с передачей функции в конструктор при создании объекта:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef void (*func_ptr)(int);

class TestClass {
public:
    TestClass(func_ptr _ptr);
public:
    func_ptr  method;
};

TestClass::TestClass(func_ptr _ptr) : method(_ptr) {
}

void method_plus(int _arg) {
    std::cout << _arg + 1 << std::endl;
}

void method_minus(int _arg) {
    std::cout << _arg - 1 << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    TestClass tc1(method_plus), tc2(method_minus);

    tc1.method(42);
    tc2.method(42);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно, но так как ваша кокретная цель неизвестна, я приведу простой пример:

```
class Sample_class {
    static int k;
    int n;
    void f() { cout << " f" << n << ' ' ; }
public:
    Sample_class()  { n = k++;  }
    void some_function(){
       for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
           f();
    }
};
int Sample_class::k = 0;

int main()
{   
    Sample_class x, y, z;
    x.some_function();
    cout << endl;
    y.some_function();
    cout << endl;
    z.some_function();
    return 0;
}
```